# Numpy python R eqivalent indexing

Tags: python, r, numpy, data-science

```
import numpy as np

o = np.array([

              [
              [1,2,3,4],
              [5,6,7,8]
              ],

              [
              [9,10,11,12],
              [13,14,15,16]
              ]

             ])
print(o.flatten())

# array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
```

It first flattens the row of each matrix

But I want that it flattens the coluumn of each matrix first so that it prints
[1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8,9,13,10,14,11,15,12,16]

I tried searching and what I found was passing "F" as an argument but that gives [1,5,9,13,2,6,10,14,3,7,11,15,4,8,12,16]
that is it switches to another matrix without completing first.

In short, I would like to find python equivalent of R's indexing with double brackets

```
someData <- rep(0, 2*3*4);
ar <- array(someData, c(2, 3, 4));  
ar[1,1,1] = 1
ar[1,2,1] = 2
ar[1,3,1] = 3

ar[2,1,1] = 4
ar[2,2,1] = 5
ar[2,3,1] = 6

ar[1,1,2] = 7
ar[1,2,2] = 8
ar[1,3,2] = 9
print(ar[[1]]) # 1
print(ar[[2]]) # 4
print(ar[[3]]) # 2
print(ar[[4]]) # 5 
print(ar[[5]]) # 3
print(ar[[6]]) # 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by doing a [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) on the second dimension, and then [`flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) in column-major order as you also mentioned:

```
np.concatenate(o, axis=1).flatten(order='f')
```

**Output**

```
array([ 1,  5,  2,  6,  3,  7,  4,  8,  9, 13, 10, 14, 11, 15, 12, 16])
```